# Regex: Match string pattern with AND condition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

Is there a regex which can match the strings 1 and 2 but not 3:

1. TABLE_SP_02.csv.gz --match
2. TABLE.csv.gz --match
3. TABLE_REMARK.csv.gz --not match

I have many files with TABLE_SP format so I would like to match String 2 and all other string starting with TABLE_SP

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I tried a few regex patterns. I was able to individually match String 1 and 2. I could write a regex to match them both together. I am using regex_substr function in Snowflake for the same. I tested out the pattern in regex 101:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e1cW.png)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to match vs not? why not #3

Comment: https://regexr.com/76sto - this should help, `TABLE(_SP|\.)` - string `TABLE` followed by either `_SP` or a period (`.`)

Comment: @CanO'Spam This regex expression did not work. It only matched TABLE_SP_01.csv.gz and not TABLE.csv.gz

Comment: @depperm  I have multiple files in a folder: Examples: Dim_Person.csv.gz, Dim_Person_SP_01.csv.gz, Dim_Person_SP_02.csv.gz, Dim_Person_Traits.csv.gz, Dim_Person_Traits_SP_01.csv.gz. I want the regex to match all the file names for only File 1: Dim_Person.csv.gz, Dim_Person_SP_01.csv.gz, Dim_Person_SP_02.csv.gz.

Comment: you still haven't explained exactly why some should match vs others not. Any answer is going to be making assumptions about what should/shouldn't match

Comment: @depperm There are two target tables: Dim_Person and Dim_Person_Traits. I want data from Dim_Person.csv.gz, Dim_Person_SP_01.csv.gz, Dim_Person_SP_02.csv.gz to go in Dim_Person table. So I want to only match these file names so that their data is loaded in corresponding table

Comment: @CanO'Spam It worked! Thank you! I had to make a slight adjustment but it was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This matches the first 2 but not the 3rd.

```
^TABLE(_SP|\.)(.*)?csv.gz$
```

https://regex101.com/r/UE9I5C/1